# jQuery show/hide margin issue

Tags: jquery, animation

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".text-button-degree").click(function(){
var ul = $(this).next("ul");
if (ul.is(":hidden")) {
    ul.show(300);
} else {
    ul.hide(300);
}
  });
});
</script>
```

---

```
#engineering_small  { 
background-image:url(img/faculty_icons/engineering_small.png);  
width:25px;  
height:25px;
}

.degree-list-group  {
display:none;
}

.degree-list-group li   {
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:15px;
font-size:12px; 
}

.text-button-degree {
background:none !important;
border:none !important;
margin-left:10px;
padding-left:0px;
margin-top:-1px;
color:#ff6445 !important;
font-size:18px !important;
}
```

---

```
<div>
<div id="engineering_small" style="float:left;"></div>
<input type="button" name="sort-div" value="Architecture" class="text-button-degree"/>                          
<ul class="degree-list-group">
    <li><a href="#">Architecture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Civil engineering</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Everything works as it should; the ul unrolls as needed, though, I need to change the font-size of the button. When I do that, the code still works, though, the roll motion is sort of weird. The ul is shifted to the right a bit on the start of the animation, and when the animation ends, it jumps to the position where it should be.

I have no idea what's causing this, but apparently, font-size of the button seems to be involved.

Comment: ugh, nevermind, found the issue. margin-top:-1px was doing it.

Comment: post it as your own answer then

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found out that margin-top:-1px; was causing the issue.